# Как найти определённых людей из участников группы вконтакте

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть группа вконтакте в которой среди участников мне нужно выбрать всех девушек по имени Люба или Любовь. После этого желательно выбрать по возрастному интервалу. Искать вручную очень долго, так как в поиск подгружается только те контакты, которые "проскролились", как я полагаю таким образом они частями достаются из БД. Нужно готовое решение(желательно), так как я ни разу не веб программист, пишу на C++ и немного на javaScript. Осваивать веб программирование времени нет, но некоторые основы знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно делать запрос по типо:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "https://vk.com/al_search.php", //страница поиска
 data: {al:'1',
        c[age_from]:'20',     //Возраст от
        c[age_to]:'30',       //Возраст до
        c[group]:'135150492', //Ид группы
        c[photo]:'1',
        c[q]:'Любовь',        //Имя
        c[section]:'people',
        offset:'20'           //Для загрузки следующих участников
        change:'1'
       },
 success: function(msg){
  console.log( "Прибыли данные: " + msg);
 }
});
```

Ну это приблизительный пример, как с помощью запроса получить нужных участников группы, конечный вариант зависит от условий применения. Нужно еще из запроса считывать параметр summary, который указывает на общее количество участников найденных по этому запросу и потом исходя из этого устанавливать параметр offset запросу и считать количество уже полученных участников.

Comment: Без предварительной авторизации, и запроса с куками - это не сработает.